# Python: getting an object's “attribute/method/property” either as a parameter to a method or as a property

Tags: python, windows, wmi, properties

In the WMI module (yeah, my boss wants me to program in Windows — but at least it’s not in COBOL), it seems that you can access a WMI value either by passing it’s name as a string parameter of a method,

```
blabla=wmithingy().getvalue('nameOfValue')
```

or as a property/method:

```
blabla=wmithingy().nameOfValue()
```

Am I dreaming, smoking bad weed, or can it effectively be done (and how)?

Comment: Do you have the source of `wmithingy()` to look at and see how it's done?

Answer (score 2):

Either the `getvalue()` method uses [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr), or the [`__getattr__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method defers to the `getvalue()` method.